# Given $Hom(X,Y)$, what is the dual, $Hom^{\circ}(X,Y)$

Tags: category-theory

Going through what I thought I had learned about category theory, I find myself a bit unsure about something very elementary: Given a category $C$ with $x, y \in C$, we have the set of morphisms $Hom_C(X,Y)$ (assuming a small category), as well as the dual category, $C^{\circ}$, with its $Hom_{C^{\circ}}(Y,X)$. However, I came across the notation $Hom^{\circ}_C(X,Y)$, and I don't understand it. I mean, is $Hom_C(X,Y)$ even a category? I can't spot the morphisms, at least apart from the identities. Has age finally caught up with me?

Comment: Without some more context, it's not obvious what that would mean.

Comment: For 2-categories, $\mathsf{Hom}(X,Y)$ would be a category, but I would expect the dual to be written as $\mathsf{Hom}(X,Y)^{op}$ not $\mathsf{Hom}^{op}(X,Y)$. It's probably not this, though, as I imagine you'd be aware of working with 2-categories. It's probably just a typo or maybe it has some meaning specific to the source. There's no way for us to know without knowing what the source is or having more context.

Comment: I found the explanation: I haven't learned to read properly! I didn't have the book in front of me when I wrote this, and the author used a different notation: $Hom_C(X,Y)$ is called $C(X,Y)$, the dual of $C$ is $C^{op}$, and what I mistakenly remembered as $Hom^{\circ}_C(X,Y)$ was actually $C^{op}(X,Y)$, which makes a lot more sense, being $Hom_{C^{op}}(X,Y)$. But thank you both for trying to make sense of my nonsense. (I'll edit my original question)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n: It would be best to undo your edit and post it as an actual answer to the question.

Comment: @Hurkyl: OK - it just feels slightly wrong to answer my own question, somehow,

Comment: @j4nd3r53n It's perfectly allowed, as indicated in [this part of the FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I didn't remember what the book actually said - I didn't have the book in front of me when I wrote this, and the author used a different notation: $Hom_C(X,Y)$ is called $C(X,Y)$, the dual of $C$ is $C^{op}$, and what I mistakenly remembered as $Hom^{\circ}_C(X,Y)$ was actually $C^{op}(X,Y)$, which makes a lot more sense, being $Hom_{C^{op}}(X,Y)$. So, mystery solved.